# PHP: Performance when looping huge datasets

Tags: php

I'm interested in knowing the best way (performance and best practice wise) to handle looping of huge datasets.

Lets say you have a result from a query with thousands of rows with a lot of data.

You need to loop all those and see if something matches the date string from another loop. If it matches -> Append it to the date array which will be the actual result set.

The same dataset needs to be looped very many times to get all the matches.

Is it better to:

- Unset the dataset array key when match is found to shrink the array - resulting in a empty dataset at the very end?
- Leave it unchanged and just unset it when all the looping is done?

Example code:

```
$dates = ['2022-01-01' => [], '2022-01-02' => []]; // Hundreds of dates

$dataset = ['manyThousandRowsOfData']; // Thousands of heavy rows

foreach($dates as $date => $dateData){
    foreach($dataset as $key => $data){
        if($data['date'] !== $date){
          continue;
        }

        $dates[$date] = $data
        unset($dataset[$key]); // Unset? Or leave it be?
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should have a look functions like `memory_get_peak_usage` or `microtime` to test performances and memory usages with each of your different ways. IMO, memory peaks won't change. If you really want to limit memory usages, you shouldn't directly store your heavy rows in a dataset. But load rows (from your db?) line by line, analyze them and immediately drop them. We need more information about your persistent layer.

Comment: I would try to write a query that does the searching in the database.

Comment: I was going to say, why can't you use a `WHERE` in the database to search?

Comment: This was more about the performance of doing one over the other presented with an example case like this. The total picture of the case that made me question this is much larger and more complex but involves this kind of examples.

Comment: In general I avoid changing an array I am looping through. I consider it bad practice.

Comment: thousand of rows can be indexed by B-tree once... or caching it if it is possible . might decrease N^2 to NLogN . maybe u are using a wrong db. NoSQL might be  a better choice.